# Convert existing ed25519 private key file in openssl "private" format into ssh/ssh-keygen format using python3

Tags: python-3.x, openssl, ssh-keygen

I have an existing ed25519 keypair generated by `openssl` stored in files.  The key files are in `openssl` "private" format, e.g. (these are sample keys; no secrets):

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEIH7sjlQYpBCnodJqPqYS2441L4wOOqyfLoc/SzTTC1h8
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MCowBQYDK2VwAyEAsXTnNvb1du7vk97WGRlaieCen309UgxWB8wrBCDkw0M=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

This is not compatible with `ssh` and `ssh-keygen`.  Yes, `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` will create a "traditional" key representation that works e.g.:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAMwAAAAtzc2gtZW
QyNTUxOQAAACBMZub0hW74ge0Wu28BfB/Iz2mNRtKnHPgYJ1LC2jU5DQAAAKhm8WwCZvFs
AgAAAAtzc2gtZWQyNTUxOQAAACBMZub0hW74ge0Wu28BfB/Iz2mNRtKnHPgYJ1LC2jU5DQ
AAAECLh2ll7FW4jaIxre5HDfTP/Zt4mubZ12oLtlx7PNEiN0xm5vSFbviB7Ra7bwF8H8jP
aY1G0qcc+BgnUsLaNTkNAAAAHmJ1enpAQnV6enMtTWFjQm9vay1Qcm8tMy5sb2NhbAECAw
QFBgc=
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

but I cannot generate new keys; I must use the existing `openssl`-generated key and convert it to something I can use in `ssh`.

It is my understanding that in fact there is no direct conversion using command line utils.  I am happy to use `python3` and the `ecdsa`, `cryptography`, and other modules to perform this conversion.  I have tried all sorts of things including:

```py
import base64
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ed25519

private_key_data = 'MC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEIH7sjlQYpBCnodJqPqYS2441L4wOOqyfLoc/SzTTC1h8' # We will deal with reading the file and dropping header/footer later
# Decode the base64 data                                                                    
private_key_bytes = base64.b64decode(private_key_data)

# Create an Ed25519 private key object                                                      
private_key = ed25519.Ed25519PrivateKey.from_private_bytes(private_key_bytes)

# Serialize the private key to PEM format                                                   
private_key_pem = private_key.private_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
    encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
)
# Get the private key as a string                                                           
private_key_pem_str = private_key_pem.decode('utf-8')

print(private_key_pem_str)
```

but every variation ends up with something similar to:

```
ValueError: An Ed25519 private key is 32 bytes long
```

I am pretty much stuck trying to create an internal object from this `openssl` generated private format. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted private Ed25519 key has PKCS#8 format, the posted public Ed25519 key has X.509/SPKI format. Both keys are PEM encoded.
Indeed, the pyca/cryptography library supports conversion to OpenSSH format as follows:

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_pem_private_key, load_pem_public_key

# Private key
pkcs8Pem = b"""-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEIH7sjlQYpBCnodJqPqYS2441L4wOOqyfLoc/SzTTC1h8
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"""

privateKey = load_pem_private_key(pkcs8Pem, password=None)
privateOpenSshPem = privateKey.private_bytes(
   encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
   format=serialization.PrivateFormat.OpenSSH,
   encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
)
print("private key:\n", privateOpenSshPem.decode())

# Public key
x509SpkiPem = b"""-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MCowBQYDK2VwAyEAsXTnNvb1du7vk97WGRlaieCen309UgxWB8wrBCDkw0M=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"""

publicKey = load_pem_public_key(x509SpkiPem)
publicOpenSsh = publicKey.public_bytes(
   encoding=serialization.Encoding.OpenSSH,
   format=serialization.PublicFormat.OpenSSH
)
print("public key:\n", publicOpenSsh.decode())
```

with the output:

```
private key:
 -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAMwAAAAtzc2gtZWQyNTUx
OQAAACAsGlh6oOzQbqjPJJhZTH330iDsRuPpJDvLpN+Fj5oj5QAAAIg7VSakO1UmpAAAAAtzc2gt
ZWQyNTUxOQAAACAsGlh6oOzQbqjPJJhZTH330iDsRuPpJDvLpN+Fj5oj5QAAAEB+7I5UGKQQp6HS
aj6mEtuONS+MDjqsny6HP0s00wtYfCwaWHqg7NBuqM8kmFlMfffSIOxG4+kkO8uk34WPmiPlAAAA
AAECAwQF
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----

public key:
 ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAILF05zb29Xbu75Pe1hkZWongnp99PVIMVgfMKwQg5MND
```

---

Some info about the formats: The posted PKCS#8 and X.509/SPKI keys are PEM encoded. If in the body the line breaks are removed and a Base64 decoding is performed, this results in the DER encoded key. [DER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding) is an encoding for [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1), an interface definition language.
To display the ASN.1, it is best to load the key into an ASN.1 parser, e.g. [https://lapo.it/asn1js/](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEIH7sjlQYpBCnodJqPqYS2441L4wOOqyfLoc_SzTTC1h8), e.g. PEM encoded or as Base64 encoded DER, e.g. for the private key:

[image]

On the left is the ASN.1 key, on the right is the DER encoding. For Ed25519, the last 32 bytes are the *raw* private key (and in the case of the public key, the *raw* public key).
In contrast, no ASN.1 is used for the private key in the OpenSSH format. A detailed description of this format can be found e.g. [here](https://coolaj86.com/articles/the-openssh-private-key-format/), section *OpenSSH Private Keys*.

---

**EDIT** - Regarding your comment:

The problem is probably not with the transformation: If you use pyca/cryptography to convert a private and public key from OpenSSH format to OpenSSL format (PKCS#8, X.509/SPKI) and back to OpenSSH format, you get the same OpenSSH keys (except, of course, the OpenSSH comment, which is lost in this reconstruction, since such a comment is not stored in the OpenSSL format).

Contrary, a more likely cause for the problem would be non-associated keys: `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` creates a *key pair*, i.e. a private and public key that *belong* to each other. However, the keys you posted are *not associated*, so they belong to two different key pairs. This can be verified by deriving the public key from the private key with:

```
openssl pkey -in <path to private key> -pubout
```

which results for the posted private key in:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MCowBQYDK2VwAyEALBpYeqDs0G6ozySYWUx999Ig7Ebj6SQ7y6TfhY+aI+U=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

and is not identical to the posted public key. It is possible that this is also true for your *real* keys. If so, this could be an explanation for your approach failing.

To check whether the transformation is the cause of the problem, you could convert a key pair in OpenSSH format (which you created with `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` and checked that it works) to OpenSSL format (PKCS#8, X.509/SPKI) and back to OpenSSH format using pyca/cryptography. Then you could check with these re-transformed OpenSSH keys if it works. If so, the problem is not with the transformation, but most likely with your real keys.
Alternatively, you can post a working (but non-productive) key pair in OpenSSH format, I'll do the transformation, and you check the back-transformed OpenSSH keys on your end.

Comment: I wish this worked but it does not.    The output key formats look correct but when I take the public key and add it to `.ssh/authorized_users` and call `ssh -S none -i ./private_key.pem` , I get `Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).`   If I use the same procedure with private and public keys generated by `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` it does work.  This is OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti - I don't think the transformation is the problem. I have elaborated on this a bit in the EDIT section of my answer.

Comment: Embarrassed to say it was a cut and paste accident and the posted public and private keys were *not* paired.   I regenerated fresh keys with `openssl`, carefully copied the contents, and the answer works.   I appreciate the patience and detail.

Answer (score 0):

If you `base64decode` the private key `MC4CAQAwBQYDK2VwBCIEIH7sjlQYpBCnodJqPqYS2441L4wOOqyfLoc/SzTTC1h8`, you will take `48 bytes`. The right length of a Ed25519 private key is `32 bytes`.

After some research and testing, found out that the first 16 bytes (or `302e020100300506032b657004220420` in hex format) is the prefix of a Ed25519 private key, so sort answer is just change:

```py
private_key = ed25519.Ed25519PrivateKey.from_private_bytes(private_key_bytes)
```

to this:

```py
private_key = ed25519.Ed25519PrivateKey.from_private_bytes(private_key_bytes[16:])
```

Comment: OK!   "Halfway there."   So now how to write out in SSH compatible ("traditional" format?   The `private_key.private_bytes()` function fails with `ValueError: Unsupported key type for TraditionalOpenSSL`

Comment: Please, submit your code about this error because I do not fully understand your comment.